# detecting print settings

Tags: .net, asp.net, printing

I use a third party report viewer that handles viewing and printing reports.  To print a report, I use their print method that takes printer settings as a parameter.

If I use the `printer.printersettings` class, doesn't that get the default printer settings on the server?

How can I get the printer settings on the client machine?  Is this possible with JavaScript/AJAX, or is that a security risk?

Comment: is that "third party report viewer" *designed* for client-side usage; I have this vision of your web-server trying to spool the printouts for all of your users...

Comment: They made the report view in ajax so i guess it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely impossible to get the client's printer settings.

Comment: that sucks.  Back to the drawing board then.